# Graphing rational expressions of trig/exp by hand?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, solid-of-revolution

In my math class, we are not allowed to use calculators. Thus, when I see problems with an exponent/log or trig either in top or bottom and I have to graph them to solve the problem, I'm not sure where to start. Could someone give pointers as to how I should approach this?

For example: (functions that follow this type of format)

1. (e^x / sinx)
2. (e^x / 6x)
3. (sinx * e^x / cosx)
4. sqrt(1-e^x)

Similarly, why does sqrt(1+x^2) look similar to the absolute value function when the sqrt function and parabola is combined? Should I be looking at domain/range of outer to inner?

Comment: Well, $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ should look like one branch of a hyperbola (because it is), asymptotically approaching $|x|$.

Comment: There's something of an art to sketching, but a few basic tricks are generally useful. Just to clarify, if you know the graphs of $f$ and $g$, do you know (or have some idea) how to sketch (i) the sum $f+g$? (ii) the product $fg$? (iii) the reciprocal $1/f$? (iv) the composition $g \circ f$?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang No, I don't have any idea on how to do that

Comment: Those would be good skills to learn and practice. I'm not sure an answer would be a good fit for the site because the scope would be broad, but there are surely sites where manual graphing is explained, at least for various types of function. If you have access to a math library, a precalculus book from about the 1960s should have explanations of the issues I asked about in the previous comment. One other idea: Use a graphing utility to "reverse engineer" your functions by breaking them down as sums, products, and compositions; let the software graph and look for visual relationships.